# Detailed Stockfish Evaluation Function

Tags: stockfish, evaluation

Stockfish contains the nice 'eval' command that prints out the detailed score of its static evaluation function. It regards Mobility, Material, Bishop, Rooks, etc. However, I was wondering if there was any possibility to get even more detailed scores, like, for example the ones provided at https://hxim.github.io/Stockfish-Evaluation-Guide/

Ideally, I am looking for a tool that takes as input an epd string and returns the evaluation scores for all the subterms listed in the above page (there should be about 100 of them).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll need to do it yourself or pay someone to do it. I'm not aware there is any free download for you. Not super challenging but tedious.